# Minipage with \paperwidth: can't remove left indent

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to typeset a full-width header. But the trivial way with the minipage for some reason gives an indent to the left. It only appears when `\paperwidth` width is used.
I just can't figure out where it comes from.

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[paperheight=210mm,
            paperwidth=148mm,
            top=10mm,
            bottom=10mm,
            left=10mm,
            right=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
            
\begin{document}

\noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by indent? You have a left margin of 10mm, and so naturally the minipage starts there.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the basic thing. But how can I implement it then? Maybe use Tikz?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but you can always move left with `\hspace*{-1cm}`